# how to get java script values in php page

Tags: php

how to get java script variable in php page....
this is my code....

two values are there in output(output values=1,2)
so i want the value of output 
in php page separate variable

(i.e) in php page:`$firstvalue=1; $secondvalue=2;`

but $rowss show only first value in my php page.........

how do it....may u help me........

```
 function  filenames(output)
    {

    {
    dataps = "rowdatas=passs&output="+output;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "datainsert.php",
        data: dataps,

        error:function()
        {alert("sorry5")
        },
        success: function(html)
        {
            $('#divlistss').html(html);
            alert(html)


        }
    });
    }       

    } 

<!--datainsert.php-->
$rowdatas = (isset($_REQUEST['rowdatas']) and $_REQUEST['rowdatas'] != '' ) ? $_REQUEST['rowdatas'] : '';  
    {
    if($rowdatas == "passs")
    {
         $rowss=$_REQUEST['output'];
         echo $rowss;

         }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter this line:

```
data: dataps,
```

to

```
data: {rowdatas: 'pass', output: output},
```

and remove dataps line in js.

This way you can post multiple variables.

edit: tip: I would use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST

edit2 after comment:
If I got you correctly, you want to get each output parameter to be an individual parameter to be proecess in PHP. then I would alter the output like this:

```
var output = ''; for (var i in myarray) { output = output + '&' + i + '=' + myarray[i] + '\n'; }
```

and alter this line

```
 type: "POST",
```

to:

```
 type: "GET",
```

and it should work.

Comment: If I got you correctly, what I mentioned should work. In your code, alter POST to GET and retry, that may work, too. Can you please exactly specify the structure of js variable of output ? (If output is holding more than one variable, I would set each of them as a new post or get data)

Comment: How is the output's structure ? Unless I see it I cannot provide you an exact solution.

Comment: Updated my answer. If I got it correctly this should work now

Comment: Suggestion: give an id to form like <form id="theform">, and in jquery just serialize all form elements with simply doing this: var output= $('#theform').serialize(); . Check here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ you can get all form names and values easier this way.

Comment: Have you checked the examples in the jquery serialize page ? if I got you correctly that's exactly what you meant.

Comment: Sorry, either I can't get you, or you already have the answer here and can't put it together. And I am not willing to give personal/private support